# Python List comprehension Remove same tuples but different order

Tags: python, duplicates, tuples, list-comprehension

I have the given lists:

```
breads = ["Weissbrot", "Vollkorn", "Dinkel", "Speckbrot"]
patties = ["Wildschwein", "Rind", "Halloumi", "Aubergine"]
souces = ["Kaese", "Knoblauch", "Curry"]
toppings = ["Kopfsalat", "Bacon", "Tomate"]
```

I have written the following code:

```
burger = [(bottom, patty, souce, topping, top)
          for bottom in breads
          for patty in patties
          for souce in souces
          for topping in toppings
          for top in breads
          if bottom != top
          if (bottom, patty) != ("Speckbrot", "Aubergine")
          and (top, patty) != ("Speckbrot", "Aubergine")
          and (patty, souce) != ("Aubergine", "Kaese")
          and (patty, topping) != ("Aubergine", "Bacon")
          and (patty, bottom) != ("Halloumi", "Speckbrot")
          and (patty, top) != ("Halloumi", "Speckbrot")
          and (patty, topping) != ("Halloumi", "Bacon")]

print(len(burger))
```

This will print out the different combinations of burgers, 276 at this moment. The correct amount is 138.
The problem is that this includes duplicates like

`('Weissbrot', 'Wildschwein', 'Kaese', 'Kopfsalat', 'Vollkorn')`

`('Vollkorn', 'Wildschwein', 'Kaese', 'Kopfsalat', 'Weissbrot')`

You can see that bottom and top are the same in both tuples but in a different order.
How can i remove these duplicates. It must be done through list comprehension.

Comment: It's an exercise for university and they want it to be done through list comprehension

Comment: If this is an assignment, please include the *precise* requirements in the question. Have a look at the [ask] page and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this by using `product` and `combinations` from the `itertools` module. In particular, `combinations` lets generate all unique pairs of 2 different breads. Then use `product` to generate the list of bread-pair/patty/sauce/topping choices.

```
from itertools import product, combinations


bread_choices = combinations(breads, 2)
choices = product(bread_choices, patties, souces, toppings)

burger = [(bottom, patty, souce, topping, top)
           for (bottom, top), patty, souce, topping in choices
               if (bottom, patty) != ("Speckbrot", "Aubergine")
               and (top, patty) != ("Speckbrot", "Aubergine")
               and (patty, souce) != ("Aubergine", "Kaese")
               and (patty, topping) != ("Aubergine", "Bacon")
               and (patty, bottom) != ("Halloumi", "Speckbrot")
               and (patty, top) != ("Halloumi", "Speckbrot")
               and (patty, topping) != ("Halloumi", "Bacon")]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just check that `bottom <= top" to get unique combinations:

```
breads = ["Weissbrot", "Vollkorn", "Dinkel", "Speckbrot"]
patties = ["Wildschwein", "Rind", "Halloumi", "Aubergine"]
souces = ["Kaese", "Knoblauch", "Curry"]
toppings = ["Kopfsalat", "Bacon", "Tomate"]

burger = [(bottom, patty, souce, topping, top)
          for bottom in breads
          for patty in patties
          for souce in souces
          for topping in toppings
          for top in breads
          if bottom != top
          if (bottom, patty) != ("Speckbrot", "Aubergine")
          and (top, patty) != ("Speckbrot", "Aubergine")
          and (patty, souce) != ("Aubergine", "Kaese")
          and (patty, topping) != ("Aubergine", "Bacon")
          and (patty, bottom) != ("Halloumi", "Speckbrot")
          and (patty, top) != ("Halloumi", "Speckbrot")
          and (patty, topping) != ("Halloumi", "Bacon")
          and bottom <= top]

print(len(burger))
# 138
```

Comment: could you explain this to me?